# I can't use react-calendar-datetime-picker in React project built with vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

Install react-calendar-datetime-picker and every time I try to launch the project it just goes blank. This is the error it gives me in the console:

```
    [ERROR] [plugin vite:dep-scan] Failed to resolve entry for package "react-calendar-datetime-picker". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json: Failed to resolve entry for package "react-calendar-datetime-picker". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.

    node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:38290:10:
      38290 │     throw new Error(`Failed to resolve entry for ...
            ╵           ^

    at packageEntryFailure (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:38290:11)
    at resolvePackageEntry (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:38286:9)
    at tryNodeResolve (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:38093:20)
    at Context.resolveId (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:37901:28)
    at Object.resolveId (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:36470:55)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async resolve (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:36682:26)
    at async /home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:36839:34
    at async callback (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:921:28)
    at async handleRequest (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:701:30)

  This error came from the "onResolve" callback registered here:

    node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:36829:18:
      36829 │             build.onResolve({
            ╵                   ~~~~~~~~~

    at setup (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:36829:19)
    at handlePlugins (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:843:23)
    at Object.buildOrServe (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1137:7)
    at /home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2079:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.build (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2078:14)
    at Object.build (/home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1927:51)
    at /home/guille/Documentos/pg_4/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:36630:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)

  The plugin "vite:dep-scan" was triggered by this import

    src/components/Calendar/Calendar.jsx:2:23:
      2 │ import  DtPicker  from 'react-calendar-datetime-picker'
        ╵                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-611778e0.js:38290:10: ERROR: [plugin: vite:dep-scan] Failed to resolve entry for package "react-calendar-datetime-picker". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json: Failed to resolve entry for package "react-calendar-datetime-picker". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
Failed to resolve entry for package "react-calendar-datetime-picker". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json: Failed to resolve entry for package "react-calendar-datetime-picker". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
```

This is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.9.0",
    "@date-io/moment": "^2.13.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.5.0",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.13.3",
    "@material-tailwind/react": "0.3.4",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.4",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "jalaali-js": "^1.2.4",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.7.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-calendar-datetime-picker": "^1.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.0.10",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "tw-elements": "^1.0.0-alpha12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.0.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "vite": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

And my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

that could be happening? How can I solve that?
I need to use this library since it is the most customizable and with the best documentation

Comment: Can you post your "package.json" and the Vite config file ?

Comment: Yes... 
I already edited my publication